# Rewriting code with many nested loops

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations

I'm wondering whether how you can write something like this recursively or using a different loop system:

```
std::string a = "00000000";
for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    a[i] = '1';
    for (int j = 0; j<8; j++) {
        if (i!=j) {
            a[j] = '1';
            ... //more for loops with the same structure
            std::cout<<a[j]<<"\n";
            a[j] = '0';
    }
    a[i] = '0';
}
```

I'm trying to print out every possible eight bit combination of 0s and 1s without using any libraries (except bitset if I have to). If I do it this way, I'll end up with 8 for loops, which is a bit much. I'm wondering whether there is a way to condense this using either recursion or a clever trick with using the standard do/while/for loops.

Comment: I don't see what that code is supposed to do, but _recursion_ is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Tail-recursion is theoretically as efficient as iteration, but gcc does not optimize it. Clang does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This task can be achieved with a simple for loop and binary operations.
Bitshift `i` by an amount, then `&` it by 1 to mask that bit.

```
#include <iostream>
void printBinary()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for(int bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--){
            std::cout << (i >> bit & 1);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, didn't even use `std::bitset`!

Comment: And in general, if you have a loop from `a` to `b` containing a loop from `c` to `d`, you can flatten them into a single loop from `ac` to `bd`.  Here, `a` = 0, `b` = 8, `c` = 0, `d` = 8.

Answer (score 3):

First, your loops are incorrect: they run from 0 to 7, inclusive, while they should be running from 0 to 1, inclusive, because a bit is either zero or one.

As far as going through all 8-bit combinations goes, you can do it with a single loop: use an `int` counting from 0 to 255, inclusive, and print its binary representation:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
    cout << bitset<8>(i).to_string() << endl;
}
```

Comment: My loops are fine since I've tried the full eight loops and you do get the desired (rather messy) output. I do appreciate your other solution though! Very clever. I can't believe I didn't think of this before.

Comment: @LinusRastegar I think I see what you did: each `if` inside the next loop became more and more complex, right? Eight nested loops with lots of `if`s like that is a tough thing to write, though.